# Match Making using GAE + ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a game in which users contact a server to find a user of their level who wants to play a game. Here is the basic architecture of a game request.

[image]

I am using `ndb` to store a waiting queue for each user level in the Google DataStore.

I am accessing these queues by their keys to ensure strong consistency (per [this article](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#eventual-consistency-in-cloud-datastore)). The entities are stored in the queue using a repeated (list of) [LocalStructuredProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types).

Questions:

1. An entity is deleted from a waiting queue because it is matched to a request. The transaction is committed but not yet applied. That same entity is matched with another request and deleted. Will this throw an error?
2. These strongly consistent accesses are limited to ~1 write/sec. Is there a better architecture that would eliminate this constraint?

One thing I've considered for the latter question is to maintain multiple queues (whose number grows and shrinks with demand).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your first question, but you might be able to simulate it with a sleep statement in your transaction.

For your second question, there is another architecture that you could use.  If the waiting queue duration is relatively short (minutes instead of hours), you might want to use memcache.  It will be a lot faster than writing to disk and you can avoid dealing with consistency issues.

Comment: Yep, was hoping someone knew the theory :).
Was worried about [memcache getting dropped](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache#what). Any idea how often that happens?

Comment: I don't know how often memcache is dropped, I understand that it depends on the total load/demand for memcache (including other users).  You can manage that by writing to both NDB and memcache.  If your queue does not have any ancestors in the key, you should not be limited by the 1 write/sec constraint, it only applies to parent keys.

Answer (score 1):

1.- If you do the entity get and the post inside a transaction, then the same entity can not be matched for a game and therefore no error and it remains consistent.

2.- The 1 write per second is sthe limit for transactions inside the same entity group. If you need more, you can shard the queue entity.

You can use a dedicated memcache or a redis instance to avoid contention. This are much faster than the datastore.

See how these guys use tree nodes to do the match making:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nWyWwY2Onc

Comment: Was worried about [memcache getting dropped](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache#what). Any idea how often that happens?

Comment: The matchmaking system in that video (using buckets of player levels) looks similar to what is proposed in the question (different queues for each level). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Memcache drops keys as it gets full. You can't controll it unless you pay for a dedicated server only for you.

Comment: the system in the video is different because it does not use repeated properties to store the actual queues.

Comment: From my experience, paying for the dedicated memcache will result is much less item getting dropped